# AMA with UXPin on on Wednesday, October 2nd, 4PM–6PM GMT+02

Tags: discussion, status-completed

First Ask Me Anything will be on Wednesday, October 2nd from 4pm-6pm GMT+02 [9am EST]

It will be with [UXPin](https://www.uxpin.com)

> UXPin is a design tool you can use throughout the whole product creation process, including prototyping, collaboration, and handoff.
>
> You can use UXPin to create wireframes, UI designs, and interactive prototypes that feel like the real product. And all that without writing any code whatsoever. Your stakeholders can understand your ideas better and collaborate on iterations in one tool, which makes it easier to develop a real product.
>
> Since UXPin is cloud-based, you can work with it from browsers, but also at desktop apps on Windows, and macOS. This design tool is used by top companies of all sizes like Microsoft and PayPal, but also software houses and freelance designers.

**Questions should be posted here leading up to the event**

The event itself will take place in these chatrooms:

- Public chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99153/commentary-for-ama-with-uxpin
- Interview chatroom: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99151/ama-with-uxpin

During the interview we will be watching the public chatroom for follow-up questions, comments, etc.

Answer (score 4):

As a front-end developer I am very, very proficient with HTML/CSS and my favorite libraries. I can create a working mock-up in no time. Why would I invest the time to get to know another tool?

Answer (score 2):

What was the motivation driving the creation of UXPin? What was the problem your product sought to solve? And do you feel you have succeeded so far?

Comment: mark completed.

Answer (score 2):

You've launched a new app against some dominant competitors -- what advice could you give other developers about getting their first few sales?

Comment: mark completed.

Answer (score 2):

I already have an Adobe CC license, and thus have access to Adobe XD. What are the main differences between this product and yours, and why would I opt for yours instead of XD?

Comment: marked complete

Answer (score 1):

What would be the pros and cons of using your software in an educational setting training graphic designers? Is your product used in any curriculum that you are aware of?

Answer (score 1):

Once a prototype is shared for testing, are any analytics gathered to help improve the prototype? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 1):

One of the biggest complaints many of our members have with the direction of the industry is towards subscription models that end up costing more, and forcing people into a system to access their files.

With UXPin are people going to be stuck with files they can't open if they decide to stop subscribing? What about the cloud files?

Comment: mark completed.

Answer (score 1):

Your site claims "It gives you everything needed to design prototypes that work like they’re the finished product."

Are there any limitations to building an actually finished product in UXPin? Without going into an exhaustive list, what approximate level of detail can one reach before going into an official online launch?

Comment: mark completed.

Answer (score 0):

As a designer, I'm very, very proficient with *Design Product X*.<sup>1</sup> I can create a beautiful mock-up in no time. Why would I invest the time to get to know *another* tool?

<sub>1. i.e. Photoshop, Illustrator, Affinity Designer, ...</sub>

Answer (score 0):

How easy is it to set up A/B testing inside your platform? Is there a  specific workflow dedicated to A/B testing? Are there any specialised analytics available?

Comment: mark completed.